# How to use PowerMock with Mockito3.x?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, powermock

I am trying to use PowerMock for the first time. Currently, my app is using Mockito 3.x. I tried to setup PowerMock with following test dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:2.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0'
```

But, this results in failing test cases with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations$Mock
```

After reading the [PowerMock doc](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#supported-versions), it seems that PowerMockito is not compatible with Mockito 3.x. If this is not the case, please help me to set up the PowerMock with Mockito 3.x

Comment: prefer `mockk` over `mockito` and `powermock` in Kotlin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [#1049](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/pull/1049), mockito 3.x is now supported by Powermock.